# Unable to run protractor using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I am able to run the protractor using command prompt.

However, when I try to run protractor using jenkins, it started the selenium server but does not execute the browser and will fail due to timeout.

Is there any configuration that I need to do at jenkins side aside from the project path?

I also have tried to install the package manually to makesure its updated.

Below is the error when I try to build/run protractor using jenkins:

```
> webhis_jasmine@ protractor C:\Users\user1\.jenkins\HISWEBJASMINE
> protractor conf.js

[12:06:44] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:06:44] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:06:46] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.190.40.39:56419/wd/hub
Started
[31mF[0mA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
[31mF[0mA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m[31mF[0m
```

i tried to run webdriver-manager update only using jenkins just to check and it is giving below error:

```
C:\Users\user1\.jenkins\HISWEBJASMINE>webdriver-manager update 
'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user1\.jenkins\HISWEBJASMINE>exit 9009
```

Here is config file:

```
// conf.js
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
exports.config = {


  capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['Patient_positive.js','Visit_positive.js'],
  suites:{
        Smoke: ['ChainLocators.js', 'Dropdown.js'],
            Regression: 'ElementBasics.js',
            Testbed: 'testbed.js',
            PatientPositive: 'Patient_positive.js',
            PatientNegative: 'Patient_negative.js',
            VisitPositive: 'Visit_positive.js',
            VisitNegative: 'Visit_negative.js',
            EpisodeCPOEPositive: 'EpisodeCPOE_positive.js'
    },
  onPrepare:function(){
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
                new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                  savePath: './test/reports/',
                  screenshotsFolder: 'images',
                  takeScreenshots: true,
                  fixedScreenshotName: true,
                  takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: false,
                  cleanDestination: false,
                  showPassed: true,
                  fileName: 'Test_Report',
                  fileNameSuffix: '',
                  fileNameDateSuffix: true
                })
              );
             },

        jasmineNodeOpts:{
            showColors: true
        }
};
```

Is it related?

Update: I strip the spec to have to only 1 'it' and run. Manage to get a success result and report is generated, but i see the browser not launched as when running using cmd prompt.

```
C:\Users\hafizan.abdmulok\.jenkins\HISWEBJASMINE>npm run protractor 

> webhis_jasmine@ protractor C:\Users\hafizan.abdmulok\.jenkins\HISWEBJASMINE
> protractor conf.js

[15:14:40] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:14:40] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[15:14:43] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.190.40.39:52793/wd/hub
Started
Successfully open patient page
Successfully enter name
Successfully select title
Successfully select gender
Successfully enter date of birth
Successfully select ID type
Successfully enter idno= 850921141112
Successfully select Nationality= Malaysia
Successfully enter mobile no
Successfully enter patient address line 1
Successfully enter patient address line 2
Successfully enter patient address line 3
Successfully enter patient postcode= 57000
Successfully enter patient city= Bukit Jalil
Successfully select patient State= Kuala Lumpur
Successfully select patient State= Malaysia
[32m.[0m


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 63.169 seconds

CGM
[15:15:52] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[15:15:52] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:15:52] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Run webdriver manager command like : "node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update"

Comment: @SadikAli i have tried run this command `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0`

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: No it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using `directConnect:true` in your config file instead of `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',`

before runing the test do the below activities

```
webdriver-manager clean

node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: currently i am not using seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', either.  at the moment i'm running protractor directly from the node_modules.  i tried to do webdriver-manager clean and reinstall too but still not working when running from jenkins.

Comment: @hafizan Could you share your `config` file

Comment: @hafizan Use `directConnect:true` in your config and try to run your test

Comment: I have put in my config. It showing [[09:30:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:30:55] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...] But at the test machine, it does not launch any browser nor executes the test. If I run it manually on command prompt, it can run perfectly.

Comment: @hafizan Try doing the pre-req in the updated answer and update the question with the error when you try to run the test with `directConnect`

Comment: I tried your suggestion webdriver manager clean and run the node commands. I also use stripped spec file with simple sequence just to test. I manage to get the success result. But i am confused on why the web browser is not launched as when run using cmd prompt?

Comment: the other problem is, due to the browser not launched, seems like it run on lower resolution causing error as object not clickable